# how to handle httpresponseredirect

Tags: python, django

test2/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views
from .forms import  forms

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^thankyou/$',views.thankyou,name='thankyou')
]
```

test1/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import url , include

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^test2/',include('test2.urls')),
    ]
```

views.py
  this view should redirect to /test2/thankyou/ but why it is going to /thankyou
and what to do enable the view given by redirect method

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
    from .forms import Get_name

    # Create your views here.
    def index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Get_name(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
        else:
            form = Get_name()
        return render(request, 'test2/name.html' , {'form':form})

    def thankyou(request):
        return HttpResponse('sai chaitanya')
```

name.html
after submitting the form it should redirect to test2/thankyou but it is going to /thankyou.

```
<form action="/thankyou/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
user_choice =[('space',''),('passenger','Passenger'),('driver','Driver')]

class Get_name(forms.Form):
    user_name = forms.CharField(label='user name',max_length='50',required=True)
    pass_word1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,max_length='20',label='Password')
    pass_word2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, max_length='20', label='Confirm Password')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='email',max_length='100')
    mobile = forms.CharField(label='contact number ',widget=forms.NumberInput,max_length='10')
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address',max_length='100')
    user_type = forms.CharField(label='select user type',widget=forms.Select(choices=user_choice))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to `/thankyou/` because you have hardcoded the URL `/thankyou/`:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
```

You can redirect to `/test2/thankyou/` by changing the code to:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect('/test2/thankyou/')
```

However the best practice is to reverse the URL instead of hardcoding it:

```
from django.urls import reverse

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thankyou'))
```

This can be simplified using the `redirect` shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('thankyou')
```